# form validation angularjs without submit button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want validation of the form which do not have the submit button.

```
    <div ng-controller="UserCreationCtrl">
        <form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputUserLogin">User Login:</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" id="inputUserLogin" ng-model="user.userLogin" placeholder="User Login" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputFirstName">First name:</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputFirstName" ng-model="user.firstName" placeholder="First name"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <span  class="nullable">
                    <select ng-model="user.lookupId" ng-options="select as speciality.lookupName for speciality in specialityList" ng-change="selectedSpecilaty()">
                        <option value="">-- choose speciality --</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div> some extra other fields goes here</div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <a ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">cancel</a>
                    <a ng-click="createNewUser()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">create new user</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

How to make the `userlogin(email)`, `firstname` and the `speciality` fields as mandatory, `email` field must be validated as email. Usually how do we do the validation of the form which do not have the submit button. I.e when I click on the 'create new user' link the form should be validated.

When the errors occured after clicking the link, the form should have correct fields data and it should display only the error messages beside the error fields or display with a field with a red color.

Can we do the client side validation of the form in the html itself without the controllers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use in $formName.$valid
All necessary input fields need required attribute.

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal" name='myForm'>
 <a ng-click="createNewUser()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">create new user</a>
</form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6zVqTeW1WARIUcbS7dC9?p=preview

Comment: validation of the fields is not working with your solution. I have given a name to the form and for the button i have added ng-disabled="myForm.$valid".

Comment: @PraveenReddy `ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid"`

Comment: Sorry i missed that ! before the code, but still the button"create new user" is disabled and when i clicked on the button the method in the controller is called without any validation.

Comment: you can use any one you like $invaid or $valid it is upto you :).updated with plukner

Comment: This is not my requirement because it is disabling the button. The button should not be disabled. After i clicked on the button it has to display the error fields without loosing the existing fields data.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

- mandatory fields are assessed using the "required" attribute (HTML5).
- email fields are assessed using the type "email" (HTML5).
- you can submit with a "submit" type button or with an "ng-click" directive, either.
- in AngularJS custom validation should be done using directives (see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)).
- here you have an example of custom validation:

---

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
  <div>
    Size (integer 0 - 10):
    <input type="number" ng-model="size" name="size"
           min="0" max="10" integer />{{size}}<br />
    <span ng-show="form.size.$error.integer">This is not valid integer!</span>
    <span ng-show="form.size.$error.min || form.size.$error.max">
      The value must be in range 0 to 10!</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    Length (float):
    <input type="text" ng-model="length" name="length" smart-float />
    {{length}}<br />
    <span ng-show="form.length.$error.float">
      This is not a valid float number!</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Here it is checking the length only. The requirement is that after the button is clicked then only the form validation should start i.e required fields validation, email validation etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form_validation" ng-submit="form_validation.$valid && submit()" novalidate> <div ng-show="form_validation.$submitted || form_validation.to_address.$touched">
   <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="form_validation.to_address.$error.required || form_validation.to_address.$error.email"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>Enter valid Email Addresses.</div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ToAddress"> To Address: </label>
    <input type="email" name="to_address" id="to_address" class="form-control" ng-model="user.to_address" ng-required="true"/>
</div>
```

try this above,
http://www.drtuts.com/handle-form-using-angularjs/

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.